# Is there an interactive options in vi where I can can create an expandable menu?

Tags: linux, shell, vi

I wan to create a file for my program that users open up and choose their options before running the calculation in a VI or other editor. Kind of like the menu in VI where you can highlight a word and expand/change to that topic. Only I want to let then highlight an option and see all the possible choices and be allowed to choose one. Is there a way to create such a file/capability?

Comment: Wow... First things first, is your "program" a *shell script*, *python*, C, C++, what? It sounds like it is a shell script, but the question isn't tagged `shell` (for POSIX shell) or bash, etc... If so, the only thing close would be, e.g. `dialog`. see [LinuxCommand.org: Dialog](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_dialog.php)

Comment: I am creating an input file for a program that is written in Fortran. The code at the beginning opens the file and reads the options for the calculation. There are several options that must be set before the calculation is ran (which optimization routine is used, thresholds, and so on). I like how in the menu of VI you have the option to put your cursor at a word and with ctrl+] you are transported to that topic menu. How do I recreate this capability in the input file with the keywords so that you can put he cursor at the keyword and see all the possible options (and possibly select one).

Comment: OK makes more sense. Why not generate a default config file at the beginning, and either write it out and invoke an editor like `vi` or display it in `dialog`, and then read the user modified config back it. FORTRAN has fairly robust string handling (for FORTRAN). Or for that matter, just create a default config to go along with your code and skip having to generate it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Sounds to me like you would be better off creating a drop-down list box to choose from with a simple Python GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain what you mean, but you could create a simple GUI in Python like this that lets your users select parameters from lists and then writes the *"settings"* file for the FORTRAN program and starts it when a button is pressed:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from guizero import App, ListBox, Text, PushButton

def StartThatPuppy():
   print("Starting FORTRAN...")
   # Write currently selected settings to config file
   # subprocess.call('/Users/fred/program.exe')

app = App(title="FORTRAN Parameter Setup", width=300, height=200)

t=Text(app, text="Select optimisation method")
listbox = ListBox(app,
                  items=["Method A", "Method B", "Method C (beta)", "Naive Method"],
                  selected="Method B",
                  scrollbar=True)
listbox.height=3
listbox.width=20

t=Text(app, text="Select threshold")
listbox = ListBox(app,
                  items=["1%", "2%", "5%", "10%"],
                  selected="5%",
                  scrollbar=True)
listbox.height=3
listbox.width=20

button = PushButton(app, text="Start FORTRAN", command=StartThatPuppy)
app.display()
```

That looks like this:

[image]

More examples and documentation are [here](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/listbox/).

---

Alternatively, if you want something textual, without needing a GUI, you could use `whiptail` like `raspi-config` uses on the RaspberryPi:

[image]

Another option might be `dialog`, documentation [here](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html#synopsis)

That could look like this:

```
dialog  --title "FORTRAN Parameter Setup" "$@" \
        --checklist "You can choose your threshold here.\n\
  Press SPACE to toggle an option on/off. \n\n\
  What threshold do you want?" 20 61 5 \
        "1%"  "Default threshold" ON \
        "2%"  "Less sensitive" off \
        "5%"  "Can be noisy" off \
        "Unlimited"    "Potentially too many results" off

retval=$?
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly an options and the sample code you provided ought to get me started.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a text-based concept, rather than graphical, in case that suits you better. The code is at https://github.com/asb/raspi-config if you want a look.